# Sort an object which is filled with arrays consisting of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

I am facing an issue where I am getting Api results which I can't modify for my convenience and I have to deal with what I got.
I get an object filled with arrays which also have objects inside them similar to this one:

```
{
sectionOne: [{game: 1, order: 3},{game: 2},{game: 3},{game: 4}],                                                       
sectionTwo: [{game: 1, order: 1},{game: 2},{game: 3},{game: 4}],
sectionThree: [{game: 1, order: 2},{game: 2},{game: 3},{game: 4}],
}
```

In all sections the first element in the array always has a key called order, which is the position the array needs to be in the object.
From the top example, the expected results should be:

```
{
sectionThree: [{game: 1, order 1},{game: 2},{game: 3},{game: 4}],                                                        
sectionOne: [{game: 1, order 2},{game: 2},{game: 3},{game: 4}],
sectionTwo: [{game: 1, order 3},{game: 2},{game: 3},{game: 4}],
}
```

PS. I know there isn't a method that can sort objects, I tried mapping them with entries, with keys but I don't know how to go deeper into the structure and target them.

Comment: What is this supposed to be, JSON? In that case, your given example data does not make sense to begin with - you can not have an object without keys.

Comment: @CBroe sorry guys I made a mistake I added the keys in the start

Comment: The answer from lejlun will do you fine, but I'd caution against using Objects as ordered collections.  Although the property order is now specified, they are logically unsorted collections of properties.  If you want order, turn this into an array (which you can do with that answer simply by skipping the `fromEntries` call.)  Also note that your suggested output doesn't match the input; presumably you want *Two*, *Three*, *One*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Destructuring Assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const obj = {
  sectionOne: [{ game: 1, order: 3 }, { game: 2 }, { game: 3 }, { game: 4 }],
  sectionTwo: [{ game: 1, order: 1 }, { game: 2 }, { game: 3 }, { game: 4 }],
  sectionThree: [{ game: 1, order: 2 }, { game: 2 }, { game: 3 }, { game: 4 }],
};

let sortedObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).sort(
    ([, [{ order: o1 }]], [, [{ order: o2 }]]) => o1 - o2
  )
);

console.log(sortedObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
arr = arr.sort((a, b) => a[0].order - b[0].order)
```

Comment: I know how to sort an array, but I need a dynamic way to restructure the object itself and sort it out

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you need function like:

```
const sortKeys = (obj) => {
return Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = obj[key];
    return acc;
}, {});}
```